# Activity which implements multiple dialog listeners?

Tags: java, android, dialog

I’m getting really confused with dialog boxes in Android and need some advice.

Everything was initially going well.  I had numerous dialogs being created within MainActivity opened via a Navi Drawer.  The dialogs where created very simply using code like this:

```
private void exportDialog() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View formElementsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.export_data, null, false);
    AlertDialog msgBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(formElementsView).setTitle("Export Responses")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_share)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Code...
                }
            })
            .create();
    msgBox.show();
}
```

But I started to notice problems when the device resumed from lock screen.  Switching/pausing/resuming worked fine, but the locked screen seemed to kill the activity context and when the app resumed the dialogs became graphically corrupt and I got the “Activity has leaked window” error message in the logs.

So, I started again.  I moved all the dialogs into DialogFragment classes which seems to be the ‘proper’ way to do it.  This removes the error and graphical glitches. Great!

But I can’t work out how to add more than one dialog listener to MainActivity.  So I’ve got:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LogInDialog.NoticeDialogListener{
```

but can I add more?

Until I work out how to do this, I’ve altered many of the MainActivity methods and moved them into the relevant dialog classes, which works fine but seems a rather linear approach.  It would be nice if MainActivity could act upon each dialog response.

As you can guess, I’m not a professional developer so I’m getting rather lost!

**UPDATE:**

OK, it seems the *original* problem of graphic glitches and "leaked window" messages was because the dialog boxes were not being dismissed correctly.  Adding the following seems to have greatly improved matters:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
     if (DialogBox1!=null){
         DialogBox1.dismiss();
     }
     DialogBox1= null;
     if (DialogBox2!=null){
         DialogBox2.dismiss();
     }
     DialogBox2= null;
     if (DialogBox3!=null){
         DialogBox3.dismiss();
     }
     DialogBox3= null;
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

use inner classes that implements LogInDialog.NoticeDialogListener

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I had played around with this idea but couldn't get them working.  I couldn't work out how to link the inner class to the dialog.  e.g.
    `private class DialogListener implements TestDialog.DialogListener {
     @Override
        public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
      //code
        }
    }`

Comment: make your inner class public

Comment: OK I make the class public and also extend Activity (or else I can't see how to pass  `.getFragmentManager()` ).  But things just start to get even more confusing because I get errors telling me the activity's been destroyed.  I'm starting to think this is belong my understanding.  Seems very difficult to show multiple custom dialogs with listeners.

Comment: Seems I'm wasting my time.  The original problem still occurs (graphical glitches when phone sleeps) and it might be because I've got a GLSurfaceView attached to a view in the Main Activity's XML layout.  When the screen rotates (to show lock screen) this seems to corrupt my app.

Comment: Final comment (promise!), seems the problem was the dialog boxes weren't dismissing correctly.  See updates in question.  Thanks for your help though, I learnt something new about inner classes.